# PyTorch multiprocessing error with Hogwild

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, multiprocessing, pytorch

I've encountered a mysterious bug while trying to implement Hogwild with torch.multiprocessing. In particular, one version of the code runs fine, but when I add in a seemingly unrelated bit of code before the multiprocessing step, this somehow causes an error during the multiprocessing step: `RuntimeError: Unable to handle autograd's threading in combination with fork-based multiprocessing. See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Autograd-and-Fork`

I reproduced the error in a minimal code sample, pasted below. If I comment out the two lines of code `m0 = Model(); train(m0)` which carry out a non-parallel training run on a separate model instance, then everything runs fine. I can't figure out how these lines could be causing a problem.

I'm running PyTorch 1.5.1 and Python 3.7.6 on a Linux machine, training on CPU only.

```python
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch import nn

def train(model):
    opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
    for _ in range(10000):
        opt.zero_grad()
        # We train the model to output the value 4 (arbitrarily)
        loss = (model(0) - 4)**2
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()

# Toy model with one parameter tensor of size 3.
# Output is always the sum of the elements in the tensor,
# independent of the input
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(3))

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sum(self.x)

############################################
# Create a separate Model instance and run
# a non-parallel training run.
# For some reason, this code causes the 
# subsequent parallel run to fail.
m0 = Model()
train(m0)
print ('Done with preliminary run')
############################################

num_processes = 2
model = Model()
model.share_memory()
processes = []
for rank in range(num_processes):
    p = mp.Process(target=train, args=(model,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
for p in processes:
    p.join()
    
print(model.x)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to explain why you need this? It seems very risky re-instantiating the same pytorch model in the same session. Also I would not recommend using multiprocessing, better switch to other backends such as gloo, mpi, nccl.

Comment: Can you share your intuition on why this would be risky? Generally I would not expect that creating different instances of one class would be problematic...in every other case of OOP I have seen, multiple instances of the same class act independently and do not interfere with each other. Also, what is the reason to avoid torch's native multiprocessing library?

Comment: There's a warning in [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#asynchronous-multiprocess-training-e-g-hogwild) about global statements. Have you tried to add `if __name__ == '__main__'`?

Comment: @roman just tried this, getting same result

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this problem, but it seems to be working fine... I am running python==3.7.4 and torch==1.2.0 and here's the output ```tensor([1.3333, 1.3333, 1.3333], requires_grad=True)```. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try using the latest torch==1.5.1?

Comment: @rampatowl Have you had any success with Hogwild training distributed across multiple nodes?

Answer (score 8):

If you modify your code to create new processes like this:

```
processes = []
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
for rank in range(num_processes):
    p = ctx.Process(target=train, args=(model,))
```

it seems to run fine (rest of code same as yours, tested on pytorch 1.5.0 / python 3.6 / NVIDIA T4 GPU).

I'm not completely sure what is carried over from the non-parallel run to the parallel run; I tried creating a completely new model for the two runs (with its own class), and/or deleting anything from the original, and/or making sure to delete any tensors and free up memory, and none of that made any difference.

What did make a difference was making sure that `.backward()` never got called outside of `mp.Process()` before it was called by a function within `mp.Process()`.  I think what *may* be carried over is an autograd thread; if the thread exists before multiprocessing with the default fork method it fails, if the thread is created after fork it seems to work okay, and if using spawn it also works okay.

Btw: That's a really interesting question - thank you especially for digesting it to a minimal example!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex! When I try your change, it does get rid of the runtime exception, but the training doesn't actually seem to occur--I get the original weight vector of `tensor([1., 1., 1.], requires_grad=True)` afterward. Whereas if I run the original code but without the non-parallel run I get `tensor([1.1864, 1.1864, 1.1864], requires_grad=True)` as the output. I should clarify that I am using a CPU--does `spawn` only work for GPUs?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with your setup, but it is actually learning on my computer. Strangely, I get the right (deterministic) result  of GPU, but something slightly random on cpu, for instance `tensor([1.1852, 1.1858, 1.1863], requires_grad=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

which is very important for multi-processing!

Comment: It should be __name__ == '__main__'. The "__" indicates you try to specify the global dir key otherwise you'll get NameError because the interpreter treats it as a variable.